# How to parameterize column B value when column A value is absent in rails for a friendly URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-url

I have a Product model which has several columns out of which two columns are :first_name and :last_name.

How would I parameterize value of column B(:last_name) when the value of column A(:first_name) is absent or blank.

I tried two methods below and it did not work.

```
def to_param
  if :first_name.present?
   "#{id}-#{first_name.parameterize}"
 else
   "#{id}-#{last_name.parameterize}"
end
```

Method-2:

```
def to_param
 "#{id}-#{first_name.parameterize}" || "#{id}-#{last_name.parameterize}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a one char fix, just don't use symbol in your first method.

```
def to_param
  if first_name.present?
   "#{id}-#{first_name.parameterize}"
 else
   "#{id}-#{last_name.parameterize}"
end
```